# Share avariable from a class, that starts a diffrent class in threads, to threads

Tags: python, variables, python-multithreading

To simplify my question, I'm working here with 2 dummy classes.
Now let's assume, I have these classes:

```
import threading
import random
import time



class Engine:
    def __init__(self, ticker, args):
        pass

    def run(self):
        ... #<- Trading simulation
        self.balance += trade_return #<- this is the same variable as the otehr one with this comment

        


class Main:
    def __init__(self):
        self.balance = 1000 #<- this is the same variable as the otehr one with this comment 
        self.tickers = ['BTCBUSD', 'ETHBUSD']
        self.args    = {'example_arg1':12, 'example_arg2':13}

    def launch_worker(self):
        threadlist = []
        for t in self.tickers:
            E = Engine(t, self.args)
            thread = threading.Thread(target=E.run, args=())
            threadlist.append(thread)
        
        for thread in threadlist:
            thread.start()

        for thread in threadlist:
            thread.join()


M = Main()
M.launch_worker()
```

The variable I want to edit is the one with the comment. Now how would I, thread safe of course, add "trade_return" to this variable?

For better understanding, this is what I want the code to do, of the Main class would not exist:

```
import threading
import random

lock = threading.Lock()

balance = 1000

class Engine:
    def __init__(self, ticker):
        pass

    def run(self):
        global balance
        ... #<- Trading simulation
        trade_return = random.randint(0, 10)
        print(trade_return)
        with lock:
            balance += trade_return #<- this is the same variable as the otehr one with this comment



tickers    = ['BTCBUSD', 'ETHBUSD']
threadlist = []
for t in tickers:
    E = Engine(t)
    thread = threading.Thread(target=E.run, args=())
    threadlist.append(thread)
        
for thread in threadlist:
    thread.start()

for thread in threadlist:
    thread.join()

print(balance)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You made `balance` a global in the second example.  If that's the behavior you want, why don't you just make `balance` a global in the first example as well?  Maybe I don't understand your problem.

Comment: I want to make the whole thing importable, so that I just have to pass for example self.tickers and the script does the rest itself. Maybe the way I structured the code wasn't the best idea, but I didn't think of multithreading in the beginning

and I'm in general curious how I'd do that, not minding if it's useful